# mediaelement.js > Youtube API: Does the mejs play button affect the views on YT?

Tags: youtube, count, view, mediaelement.js

I searched for quiet some time… Seems like that embedded youtube videos really need the "human click" to increase the views on the YT profile. Tried some things with the API given from YT… no luck so far.

Does the mediaelement.js do the magic?

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer from the YT js doc:

> Note: A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if it is initiated via a native play button in the player.

You can't use your own play button or enable autoplay if you want the stats... Tried it, the best way is to use the "native" youtube player with minimal UI and let the users click the "native" play button ...